# Not able to send mail from local in zend framework 2

Tags: email, zend-framework

Am trying to send mail from local to my Id. But it gives error on the "$transport->send($message);" in this function  my code is below

```
$message ->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");
$transport = new SendmailTransport();
```

the error show "error-message":"Unable to send mail: Unknown error

Comment: Looks like you missed a bit of your code, I don't see `$transport->send($message);` anywhere.

Comment: It need to be changes in any config setting am new in zf2